# Using FFmpeg to locate moov atom

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, html5

I have a library of videos, all of which *should* have been adjusted for web-streaming by putting the `moov` atom ahead of the rest of the video. This allows playback to begin before the client has completely downloaded the video.

Is there a reliable way to check if a certain video has been adjusted by locating how many bytes in the `moov` atom occurs? This is for debugging purposes only.

Comment: Just for reference for others interested in placing the moov atom in the beginning to facilitate playback see the `-movflags faststart` option or the `qt-faststart` tool in `ffmpeg`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

FFmpeg won't show you this information, really.

You could use [AtomicParsley](http://atomicparsley.sourceforge.net/) to parse the file, e.g.:

```sh
AtomicParsley input.mp4 -T
```

This will show you the location of the atoms in a tree. If the `moov` atom is at the beginning of the file, it'll have to come right after the `ftyp` atom, so you could try parsing the output, e.g. in Bash, only printing the second line and checking whether it contains `moov`:

```sh
AtomicParsley input.mp4 -T | sed -n 2p | grep -q "moov" && echo "yup" || echo "nope"
```

Comment: Haha, well… glad to help :)

Comment: Note, this will not work on YouTube DASH files.

Comment: @StevenPenny Right, DASH segments do not contain the entire Atom tree, because they're only segments, not complete ISO Base Media files.

Comment: I have two mp4 files and I'm trying to determine which to keep, but AtomicParsley crashes on both of them: `too many atoms
Aborted (core dumped)`

Comment: @Michael Seems it's limited to 1024 atoms by default. Not sure why – but the tool has not been updated in quite some time.

Answer (score 19):

Using [this `qtfaststart`](https://github.com/danielgtaylor/qtfaststart) (not the same as ffmpeg's `qt-faststart`), `qtfaststart` `-l` *input*.mp4 will display the order of the top-level atoms.

```
$ qtfaststart -l bad.mp4
ftyp (32 bytes)
free (8 bytes)
mdat (559619 bytes)
moov (52916 bytes)
$ qtfaststart -l good.mp4
ftyp (32 bytes)
moov (52916 bytes)
mdat (559619 bytes)
$
```

Comment: If you have `pip` installed you can install `qtfaststart` with `pip install qtfaststart`

Comment: You can also install with Homebrew: `brew install qtfaststart`

Comment: @BrandonDurham Homebrew didn't work for me, it installed a different program; presumably it was the ffmpeg version

Answer (score 12):

The way to do this using `ffmpeg` is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56963953/9357589) to another question. Run the following  Bash command:

```
$ ffmpeg -v trace -i file.mp4 2>&1 | grep -e type:\'mdat\' -e type:\'moov\'
```

The output will look something like this:

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55ea95500ac0] type:'mdat' parent:'root' sz: 52958326 32 52971704
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55ea95500ac0] type:'moov' parent:'root' sz: 13354 52958358 52971704
```

In this example, since `moov` appears after `mdat`, the moov atom is **not** at the beginning of the file and faststart is **not** enabled. If `moov` were to appear before `mdat`, then the moov atom would be at the beginning of the file and faststart would be enabled.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with FFprobe:

```
ffprobe -v trace infile.mp4
```

Or with [Bento4](//github.com/axiomatic-systems/Bento4):

```
$ mp4info infile.m4a
File:
  major brand:      isom
  minor version:    200
  compatible brand: isom
  compatible brand: iso2
  compatible brand: mp41
  fast start:       no

$ mp4info outfile.m4a
File:
  major brand:      isom
  minor version:    200
  compatible brand: isom
  compatible brand: iso2
  compatible brand: mp41
  fast start:       yes
```

Comment: Can you please demonstrate where in the ffprobe output this information can be found?

Comment: @forresthopkinsa, here you go: `ffprobe -v trace -i file.mp4 2>&1 | grep -e type:\'mdat\' -e type:\'moov\'` . (ffmpeg can be substituted for ffprobe). If moov appears before mdat, then it is at the front of the file and thus fast start is enabled. Via [Gyan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56963953/131415).

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, without tools, you can just read the first 50 bytes of the file. If the string "moov" is in there, you're good.